# How to retrieve more than 5 influencers from the Klout (V2) API?

Tags: api, limit, cap, klout

I'm trying to get all the influencers and influencees of a certain user from the Klout API. I'm using this call:

```
user.json/{kloutId}/influence

Influence returns two arrays:

* myInfluencers - Who influences the user
* myInfluencees - Whom the user influences
```

[[documentation]](http://klout.com/s/developers/v2)

My GET request looks like:

```
http://api.klout.com/v2/user.json/[kloutID of user]/influence?key=[API key]
```

and this is what gets returned:

```
Object
* myInfluencees: (Array[5])
* myInfluenceesCount: 25
* myInfluencers: (Array[5])
* myInfluencersCount: 15
```

The `myInfluencees` and `myInfluencers` are arrays (commented out) always capped at 5 users. Even though it tells me there are 25 and 15 in total. If I do the same call multiple times I always get the same 5 users.

Is there any way to retrieve the complete list of all influencers / influencees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something Klout offers in its standard API offering. It may be something they offer in the future, or at a different service level. If you need heightened access, you should email partners@klout.com with some details about your application, usage, and that sort of stuff.